# Camel: Jetty response encoding

Tags: spring, jetty, apache-camel

I want to use the Jetty component in a Camel environment. This is an excerpt of my spring-config.xml:

```
...
<bean id="webEnc" class="web.WebEnc" />
<camelContext>
    <route>
        <from uri="jetty:http://0.0.0.0/enc" />
        <process ref="webEnc" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
...
```

And here is the code used to return a `String`:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class WebEnc implements Processor{

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getOut().setBody("abcäöüß\"€一二三"); //the last three symbols are chinese for '123'
    }
}
```

The local address works (http://127.0.0.1/enc) but the browser does not display the string correctly (displayed as 'abcÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃŸ"â‚¬ä¸€äºŒä¸‰'). I assume the problem is *some* encoding. **How to set the encoding** like 'utf-8'?
I can't find any hint here (http://camel.apache.org/jetty.html) concerning encoding or charset or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help and hints from Łukasz (thx for your time) i found a good solution. This forces Jetty to deliver bytes, not a string:

```
exchange.getOut().setBody("abcäöüß\"€一二三".getBytes("utf-32"));
```

To help the browsers to display the correct symbols i did this:

```
exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=utf-32");
```

My firefox cannot display the chinese symbols with utf-32, it's fine with utf-8. Chrome does it with both encodings.
But actually i was not interested in that, my intention was to deliver bytes. `getBytes()` does the job.

Comment: Wouldn't .convertBodyTo() http://camel.apache.org/convertbodyto.html do the job then?

Comment: utf-32 support on web browsers isn't that great.  stick with utf-8, if you can.  note that both the html specs and the http specs are standardizing on utf-8, so should you.

Comment: @joakim: utf-8 is ok, i just want to understand the mechanism behind the scenes. Thx for the info.

Comment: @J2B: great. This also works. After some testing i found that i have to use byte[], not java.lang.String in the type attribute: `<convertBodyTo type="byte[]" charset="UTF-16" />`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to set Content-Type header with utf-8 charset in the output message, something like this:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    exchange.getOut().setBody("abcäöüß\"€一二三"); //the last three symbols are chinese for '123'
    exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
}
```

Comment: Hm. This fixes the 'problem' somehow... Firefox now shows the string correctly. But I also tried `utf-16` and `utf-32`. In both cases firefox shows strange characters. So i decided to go in more detail and read the bytes delivered from jetty. And there are always 24 bytes which means the string is always `utf-8` coded. What i want is that the bytes are delivered from jetty as needed, ie. also `utf-32`. But how to do? I also tried `Exchange.HTTP_CHARACTER_ENCODING` and `Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING` with no success.

Comment: I assumed this string is encoded with utf-8 and your browser has fonts to display it correctly. So, first you should detect character encoding of the text and set it properly. I just tried to use "gb18030" charset and it looks "nice" (like chinese fonts) in my chrome with default system fonts.